# How do I split lists in python using range?

Tags: python, range

I'm coding this for my class but I cannot figure out how to split using range.

find spell_list length
use range() to iterate each half of spell_list
label & print the first and second halves

spell_list = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "February", "November", "Annual", "Calendar", "Solstice"]

Comment: What do you mean by "split"? What should the output look like?

Comment: Can you show desired output?

Comment: `for idx in range(len(spell_list) // 2):` but usually you never use range to iterate over a list, you just iterate over the list directly: `for elem in spell_list[:len(spell_list) // 2]:` and use `enumerate()` if you need the element index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range() in a few different ways. The first time I use it, I use one argument, which uses the range 0 through int(len(spell_list)/2). The second way I use it takes 2 arguments, which the first is the lower bound of the range and the 2nd value is the max bound of the range.

```
spell_list = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "February", "November", "Annual", "Calendar", "Solstice"]

print("First half of list:\n")

for i in range(int(len(spell_list)/2)):
  print(spell_list[i])

print("\n\nSecond half of list:\n")

for i in range(int(len(spell_list)/2), len(spell_list)):
  print(spell_list[i])
```

Also, I use int(len(spell_list)/2) a couple times because len(spell_list)/2 comes out to be a float number since spell_list has an odd number of items and range() only accepts int numbers as arguments

Answer (score 1):

if you want to iterate over the half of the list you can use `range(len(list)//2)` where `len(list)//2` is half of the items in list

Comment: Why double `/` ??

Comment: this is floor division. It will round down to an integer